# How to control scrolling in grid type view

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, xcode4.6

**UPDATED** I have a grid (`SubViewGrid`) that I have drawn on a `UIView`.  I need to be able to prevent the far left column (time) from scrolling horizontally, and the top row (staff name) from scrolling vertically.

The data is drawn in `SubViewData`, which is within the `UIScrollView`.  I would imagine that I would need two (2) `UIScrollView`s here, one for the `SubViewGrid`, the other for the `SubViewData`.  Question is: how to sync them to accomplish the user's needs?

[image]

**UPDATE**  Here is the REVISED structure:

[image: revised image]

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *schedScrollView;  
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView * topGridView;  
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView * leftGridView;  
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView * topLeftView;    // TODO
```

Comment: How have you implemented this in the first place?

Comment: Implemented?  Yes, and the user came back to me with the updated requirements...right now, the left column and top row scroll with the data grid... not good!  They want it to act just like Excel, where you can lock a column/row.

Comment: I asked "_how_ have you implemented this"? How are you creating the rows and columns?

Comment: Qustion updated to respond to your questions.  I am using CG methods for the actual drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818453/1367622) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818040/make-subview-of-a-uiscrollview-fixed-while-the-other-subviews-scrollable).

I think that's how you would need to approach this problem, with the fixed heading(s) in a separate subview to the data. Then set the frame of the fixed subview in `scrollViewDidScroll:` to create the appearance of a fixed heading at the top (or side) of the scroll view.

For example: Set the initial frame of the header subview to `(0, 0, width, height)`, and then in `scrollViewDidScroll:` set the frame to `(0, contentOffset.y, width, height)`.

**EDIT:** Here's an example. In the below screenshot I set up the top row (people), left column (time), and top left cell (to hide the overlapping of the headers) inside a `UIScrollView`. Then in `scrollViewDidScroll:` I set the frames of the subviews to fix them to the top, left, and top-left respectively.

[image: Grid with fixed headers]
[image]

**ViewController.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView * theScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView * topView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView * leftView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView * topLeftView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize theScrollView, topView, leftView, topLeftView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theScrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(502, 401);
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect tempFrame = self.topView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.topView.frame = tempFrame;

    tempFrame = self.leftView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    self.leftView.frame = tempFrame;

    tempFrame = self.topLeftView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    tempFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.topLeftView.frame = tempFrame;
}

@end
```

And that's all there is to it! Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Hi Steph... you're real close... the SubViewGrid has to scroll also: vertically to match the time (runs at least 8 hours in 15 minute increments) and horizontally to match the staff, all the while keeping in synch with the SubViewData, which is a UIView drawn on the SubViewGrid (hope that makes sense).  As I mentioned above, it's like an Excel spreadsheet when you freeze columns/rows.  Will this do _exactly_ that?

Comment: @spokane-dude Yes, I think for this approach to work the top row and left column would need to be in separate subviews to the data. The `topLeftView` is just a blank view I placed in the top-left corner, because otherwise the top row and left column overlap when you scroll and it looks a bit strange. So yes, in your screenshot it's where the diagonal line is drawn. Perhaps there is a better way to implement fixed rows/columns without creating separate views, but I'm not sure how you would go about doing that.

Comment: @spokane-dude Sure, no problems. I hope you find a way to get it working.

Comment: @steph... it's not hitting _scrollViewDidScroll_ 
See update of original question for additional data.

Comment: @spokane-dude Make sure your view controller adopts the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, and you have set `self.schedScrollView.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yes, to both... I rebuilt everything as you can see from the structure.  I remember having this problem earlier on in the beginning of development, but I don't think this is the same issue; for some reason the gesture is not getting to the scrollview, I think.  I'm off for the night; will check back in the morning... thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Steph... I'm going to close this because since I have added the other UIView, this question is no longer applicable.  Thanks for your time... I'm going to try asking a different question.

Comment: Hmm, without seeing more of your code it's hard to tell why scrollViewDidscroll is not being called. No problems, and I hope you figure it out!