# iOS UIRefreshControl subview opacity similar to the attributedTitle opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` subclass that in addition to the title adds a custom control to  its subviews. It works great except of one thing, the pull-based-on-distance-opacity is applied only to the text, and not the subview.

```swift
class CustomRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
    private let customView = MyCustomView()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        addSubview(customView)
    }
```

How can I dynamically change the `customView` opacity based on the `UIRefreshControl` pull distance? I want it to be the same as the `attributedTitle` opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a dedicated way to match the opacity of the attributed title. I don't even think that `UIRefreshControl` is designed to be modified in this way, adding random subviews to it.

I would suggest creating your own view that resembles a `UIRefreshControl`, that changes its opacity and frame depending on the scroll view's `contentOffset`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818453/5133585) for a starting point.

Assuming a vertical-scroll only scroll view, you could do something like:

```
// CustomRefreshControl is just a UIView subclass
var refreshControl: CustomRefreshControl!

// this is in a UIViewController, but it should be trivial to wrap 
// a custom UIScrollView instead, if you want that.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    scrollView.delegate = self
    refreshControl = .init(frame: .zero)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        if refreshControl.superview == nil {
            scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
            scrollView.sendSubviewToBack(refreshControl)
        }
        // update the opacity
        // could be a method in CustomRefreshControl instead, to
        // encapsulate the logic
        refreshControl.layer.opacity = Float(-scrollView.contentOffset.y / 100)
        refreshControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: 100)
    } else {
        refreshControl.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this, but a really hacky solution would be to inspect the view hierarchy of `UIRefreshControl` and find that it has a subview of type `_UIRefreshControlModernContentView`. The underscore prefix suggests that this is not a stable API, so could break in future iOS versions.

As a subview of `_UIRefreshControlModernContentView`, there is a `UILabel` displaying the `attributedTitle`. You can constantly try to set that label's `layer.opacity` to your custom view's `layer.opacity`.

Since the label for `attributedTitle` appears to move when you scroll, `layoutSubviews` will be called, and you can do this in there:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    if let contentViewClass = NSClassFromString("_UIRefreshControlModernContentView"),
       let contentView = subviews.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: contentViewClass) }),
       let label = contentView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel }) {
        customView.layer.opacity = label.layer.opacity
    }
}
```

Comment: approach with tracking `scrollViewDidScroll` is what I eventually did and it works well, thanks for the example!